# Play20: Getting path of css file generated from less

Tags: playframework-2.0

I need to access the generated css file, which resides on `target/scala-2.10/resource_managed/main/public/stylesheets/` but i haven't found a good way to do it.

For now, i'm doing like this:

```
Play.getFile("target/scala-2.10/resource_managed/main/public/stylesheets/generatedFile.css").getAbsolutePath
```

But this will break on any scala version/api change. Is there any other way to get this path?

The reason i need this path is so i can print an view to PDF using Flying Saucer, so i need the local file path.